# How do I get rid of the Total Ad Performance malware from my Android?

Tags: malware, android

My Sony Xperia Z3 Compact has been infected by a malware that redirects my browsers to either one of the two websites: www.totaladperformance.com or www.admomi.com.

I have the paid version of Bitdefender in my phone, which luckily blocks the websites from opening but is unable to detect the malware in the phone.

I have even done a factory reset twice, which failed to delete the malware.